# Is this special symbol of the Laplacian for finite differences (the "pizza operator") a standard symbol?

Tags: notation, finite-differences, convention

Richardson's 1911 article [*The Approximate Arithmetical Solution by Finite Differences of Physical Problems Involving Differential Equations, with an Application to the Stresses in a Masonry Dam*](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/210/459-470/307) includes this excerpt:

[image]

Are these symbols ($\partial$ with a line through it, and what looks to me like the "pizza operator") standard, or are they just something Richardson used?

Comment: I've not seen this symbol before. I like it though.

Comment: I have not seen it either. And why they tilt nabla and drive a line through her?

Comment: thanks @gt6989b I meant to include "notation" but I kept drawing a blank when I tried to think of the correct word to describe it.

Comment: The “$\partial$ with a line through it” is the letter “eth,” which was used in Old English (and is still used in some languages such as Icelandic). I’d hazard a guess that this was a handy d-like symbol that could be typeset at the time.

Comment: @mathreadler Since the “pizza operator” isn’t simply an inverted capital delta with an extra line, it’s likely some other type slug that the printer had lying around that happened to fit the bill. I don’t recognize the glyph offhand, but if I can dig up my old German book of “all” of the world’s typescripts, it’s probably in there.